# String Find in C

Tags: c, string

What I need to do is find what position a certain string is at, and only keep what's after that.

Pseudo-code:

```
string1 = "CDSDC::walrus"
string2 = "::"
string3 = (substr( string1, strfind(string1, string2) + 2 )) // +2 being the len of str2
// at this point I want string3 == "walrus"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`strstr`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) does what you want. ie locate substrings.

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null
> pointer if str2 is not part of str1.

For your example,

```
char *string3 = strstr(string1,"walrus")
```

Or, if you want to split strings into tokens based on delimiters like `::` use can use [`strtok`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

**Split string into tokens**

> A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are
> sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters
> that are part of delimiters.

For your example,

```
strtok(string1, "::");
string3 = strtok(NULL,"::")
```

`strtok` is a tricky function in the sense that *it modifies the string you are tokenizing* and is also *not re-rentrant*. Here is a [nice article](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/strtok/) explaining the overall aspects of using `strtok`

Comment: links to cplusplus are broken, so here are updated links to [strstr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) and [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: @xdavidliu Thanks! I fixed the broken links in the answer.